# How to customize umbraco trace log viewer?

Tags: c#, logging, package, trace, umbraco7

I am using Diplo Audit Log Viewer version 1.1, and I want to know if there is a way to customize the log viewer or extend it to my needs. 
If not, is there another way or a package that has the option to customize log viewer?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what your are hoping to do? How do you want to customise/extend it?

Comment: the logger showes umbraco logs and I want to add my logs and extend the columns. @Tim

Answer (score 0):

Diplo Audit Viewer pulls out the entries from the umbracoLog table, which only contains details about actions on the content (in newer versions of Umbraco at least).

You can log your own stuff into there I believe (I've done it on much older versions of Umbraco). Anything non-content related is now logged using log4net, which you can also log to if you wish in your code.

In terms of customising the Diplo viewer, you could just fork the code and make any changes that you want, as it's open source.

If you want to log extra columns etc, you could just modify the umbracoLog table, but as it's a core bit of functionality, you probably don't want to do that in case something changes/breaks in the future. Alternative you could add your own custom table that links to the main table, keeping things nice and separate.